# Flutter method blocking, need to isolate

Tags: flutter

When I click a button and run some set state items and then call the send function, it waits until the send function is done before the set state items take effect.  I have tried to make the called function async with await on the item that takes so much time BASE64.encode of image and/or video, but still it waits.

Looking for a way to not have this function block, someone mentioned isolate, but have no idea how to work that in and examples show how to work it in the entire application not just a long running function.

```
onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    submitting = true;
                    _imageFile = null;
                    TextInputAction.done;
                  });
                  await _sendReply();
                },
```

Above is what I run on a ImageButton.  The _sendReply is below.

```
_sendReply() async {
    if (_newreplycontroller.text.isNotEmpty || myimagefile != null) {
      //_doShowSubmitting();
      DateTime dateSubmit = new DateTime.now();
      if (myimagefile != null) {
        if (isImage) {
          List<int> imageBytes = myimagefile.readAsBytesSync();
          myimage = await BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
          myvideo = 'NONE';
        }
        if (isVideo) {
          List<int> imageBytes = myvidfile.readAsBytesSync();
          myvideo = await BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
          myimage = 'NONE';
        }
      } else {
        myimage = 'NONE';
        myvideo = 'NONE';
      }
      var mymessage = _newreplycontroller.text;
      ChatServerMessage mychat = new ChatServerMessage(
          widget.mychat.msgkey,
          'message',
          widget.mychat.refid,
          widget.mychat.referralname,
          replysub,
          oid,
          oname,
          pid,
          pname,
          sender,
          sendname,
          receiver,
          receivename,
          mymessage,
          dateSubmit.toString(),
          widget.mychat.grpid.toString(),
          widget.mychat.prid.toString(),
          myfcmtoken,
          myimage,
          myvideo,
          myext);
      _doSendReply(mychat);
    } else {

    }
  }
```

From debugging I know all the time is spent on the BASE64.encode.  Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Why do you use `readAsBytesSync` inside an async function ?

Comment: I have been trying several things, what happens is that even though I make the set state changes in the on pressed, nothing happens until the _sendReply finishes, I need the progress indicator to fire from the set state of submitting change to true and it happens but after several seconds when the _sendReply finishes.  All the time is spent of the BASE64.encode.  So it was just a test and did not change the results.

Comment: as @Robert asked: Why do you use the synchronous `readAsBytesSync()` method and not `await readAsBytes()`?